# Serialize, format & sequence JSON string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON string having following format

{
    List,
    List,
    List,
    Array,
    List, 
    Array,
    List 
}

After Deserialization, as per the requirements, I am keeping all Lists in one datatable & remaining two Arrays in two separate datatables.

Now I need to Serialize it & output should be same as mentioned above.

I am using below code to serialize it

```
string toJson1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtList,Formatting.Indented);

string toJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtArray1,Formatting.Indented);

string toJson3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtArray2, Formatting.Indented);
```

How can I format it like it was before means:
It should be in same sequence of List, in between Array & then again List? 
Should I use String Manipulation or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a class that looks just like what you want to read/write:

```
public class MySomethingSomething
{
    public List<MyType> List1  {get; set;}

    public List<MyOtherType> List2 {get; set;}

    // etc
}
```

Then you can do a `myObject = new MySomethingSomething();` and fill it with data. Then you can serialize your myObject to JSON using JSON.NET.

And when you receive data like this, you just deserialize it using JSON.NET back into a fresh `MySomethingSomething` and you're all set. No hand assembly required.

Comment: Hi Roy, Thank you for your answer. It helped me. I can fill the data of "myobject" with string values by this way but how can I fill the values of Lists? In my case the values are coming in datatable having many rows? Say in your example value of List1? MySomethingSomething.Lists1 = ........?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated